# Custom wheel listener prevent ScrollPane Wheel Listener

Tags: java, swing, mouse-listeners

I add a custom mousewheellistener to my JPanel, because I will implement zoom feature for this panel which working with ctrl+mousewheel. Also my JPanel is in a JScrollpane. My problem is; when I adding MouseWheelListener to the panel, mouse wheel doesn't work for scrollpane even if Ctrl is not pressed. I want that; mouse wheel work for zoom when ctrl pressed and if not pressed it should work for scrollpane. How can I do that?

```
public class ZoomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel jZoomPanel = new JPanel();
        jZoomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
        jZoomPanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                if(e.isControlDown()) {
                // TODO implement zoom
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane jsc = new JScrollPane(jZoomPanel);

        JFrame jDemoFrame = new JFrame();
        jDemoFrame.getContentPane().add(jsc);
        jDemoFrame.setSize(300, 300);

        jDemoFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dispatch your event like this:

```
jZoomPanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if(e.isControlDown()) {
        // TODO implement zoom
        } else {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) me.getSource();
            MouseEvent newMe = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(panel, me, jsc);
            jsc.dispatchEvent(me);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work just using
```
 else {
            jsc.dispatchEvent(me);
        }
```
Also, on your answer, you created ```MouseWheelEvent e``` and then called it ```me``` later.